# Edit Text and pass string to the ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm creating the app uses weather API and I need to get name of the place from Edit Text in UI to the ViewModel and there is val which gets method from Repository. How to correctly communicate with ViewModel in my case? There is some magic spell in LiveData or I need Databinding?

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(
private val weatherRepository: WeatherRepository

) : ViewModel() {

val metric: String = "metric"

val currentWeatherByCoordinates by lazyDeferred {
    weatherRepository.getCurrentWeather() }

val forecastByCoordinates by lazyDeferred {
    weatherRepository.getForecast() }

val currentWeatherByCity by lazyDeferred { //This is what I'm writing about
    weatherRepository.getCurrentWeatherByCity("London", metric)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use live data. observe some live data method1() in ui -> change the livedata state in viewmodel by method2(city)

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you show me some example, short code etc.?